# Statistical test to find differences between percentages without knowing the size of one population

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, percentage

I need some help.

I am making a comparison between the percentage of responses to a questionnaire in my target population (N=210) and the responses at a regional level to the same questionnaire (the only data I have is, for example, that 45% responded A, 55% B - but I don't know the size of the sample) given from the Ministry of Health.

I guess I cannot do a chi squared , right?

Do you know can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Without any assumption on the size of the population this is impossible. The best thing you can probably do is make some assumptions about the size of the population.

With 45% of responses A the minimum number of samples must be at the very least 20. If you assume 20 samples and find a significant effect you'll know that it also applies if there were more samples.

You could also see how many samples you need to assume to get what p-value. You can then make an educated guess about whether there really would be at least that many samples.